# How do I remove n elements of the same value from an array in Ruby using a block / lambda expression?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm in the process of learning Ruby and I'm trying to think in a Ruby way. However, try as I might, I can't wrap my mind around this problem:

For example, I have the following source array:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5]

# param 1 = number matching, param 2 times matching
b = a.remove_repeated(5, 3)
```

Then b's value would be:

```
b = [1, 3, 4, 7, 5]
```

In the case that there were only two value values that I was trying to match, I would want them all removed as well. Such as:

```
a = [1, 4, 8, 4, 9, 2]
b = a.remove_repeated(4, 3)
```

Then b's value would be:

```
a = [1, 8, 9, 2]
```

I know how to do this a in both a iterative and a recursive way. Rather, I'm looking for a Rubyesque way of doing it.

Comment: What happens if you want to remove something for which there are not as many copies as you specified (or what if it wasn't repeated at all)?  For example: take your first array a, but do a.remove_repeated(1, 3)

Answer (score 5):

```
class Array
  def remove_repeated(obj, limit)
    reject{|e| e == obj && (limit-=1) >= 0}
  end
end
```

Array.reject copies the array one element at a time, except for the elements for which the block is true.

Comment: +1 nice solution. You could swap in `reject!` or `delete_if` for a destructive update.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this code what you're looking for?

```
class Array
  def remove_repeated(item, count)
    inject([]) do |filtered, current|
      filtered << current unless item==current && (count-=1) >= 0
      filtered
    end
  end
end

a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5]
p a.remove_repeated(5, 3) # => [1, 3, 4, 7, 5]

a = [1, 4, 8, 4, 9, 2]
p a.remove_repeated(4, 3) # => [1, 8, 9, 2]
```

Comment: as you are using inject, you can leave the state (count) in the accumulated inject([[], count]) ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to partially remove the duplicates, but if you want to remove all duplicates in a single step:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5]

b = a.uniq
# => a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5], b = [1, 3, 5, 4, 7]
```

or

```
a.uniq!
# => a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 7]
```